# Keycloak :: Your login attempt timed out. Login will start from the beginning

Tags: keycloak

When the GUI is left idle for long, the page automatically redirects to Login screen. Entering the credentials in this Login page throws error "Your login attempt timed out. Login will start from the beginning.".
The user has to reload the page and then enter the credentials to successfully login to GUI.

Could you please suggest which keycloak configuration do I need to allow user login again

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue, can't figure out why is that happening. any luck with this one ?

Answer (score 4):

To avoid this, one can change "Realm Settings → Tokens → Login timeout" to e.g. 10000 days which is 27 years, which should ensure this never happens in reality.

I've asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266761/what-is-the-reason-for-the-login-timeout-setting-and-functionality) about what the purpose of this login is, but the above is how to disable it.

Comment: It helped me years!

Answer (score 0):

The `Your login attempt timed out` error is usually indicative of Keycloak being unable to properly parse the SAML response, if you are using a SAML IdP.

This was confirmed by looking at my Keycloak logs, which had something similar to `Assertion _5c69599c-cf6a-4965-934c-6221a6b8a800 is not addressed to this SP`.

The solution in my scenario, when trying to connect to Microsoft Azure AD SAML, was to:

1. On https://portal.azure.com/, set the `Application ID URI` to `https://<host>.co/auth/realms/<realm>`
2. On the Keycloak instance, in the IdP configuration, the `Service Provider Entity ID` in the Keycloak settings also to `https://<host>.co/auth/realms/<realm>`.